# How to load CSS just in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need load `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site/dist/css/select2.min.css" />` this code just in mobile view.

How to load this CSS just in mobile view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is to include the css file irrespective of whether a device is a mobile device or desktop device and then using media queries in the css file which works for mobile and desktop devices.

but if you still need the answer then there are two major methods to do this:

**CSS WAY**

Use the `media` property of link tag: (Remember this always loads the css but activates it only on screens having max width as 960px)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 960px)">
```

**JAVASCRIPT WAY**

Use a function to determine if a device is a mobile device and if yes then apply the css:

```
function isMobile(){
    return (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test((navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera).substr(0,4)))
}
if(isMobile)
{
        var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link  = document.createElement('link');
link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css';
link.media = 'all';
head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: More details can be found in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries).

Comment: "The CSS Way" _might_ indeed be the "best" way. Depending on the size of the CSS file, making every user download it when `N` will not need it is worth considering.

Comment: The Javascript function cannot be compared with the CSS solution. The Javascript solution will not work on desktop computers that have their browser minimized to less than 960px width.